# Cognito + Social sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin

I'm integrating social sign in (facebook and google) on a website which is linked to AWS cognito. I have followed the steps in "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html" and created the login link. After a successful authentication, the user is redirected to the configured page.

The problem is that I cannot find the "id_token" after authentication.
The redirected user page looks like this "https://xasdyz.com/success.html?code=d5010c01-18ac-4942-b0d8-d5d11a1a6f05"

Is it the "code" that I need to validate using the backend? or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: your backend need to call a token service https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html to receive a token (id token, access token) based on the code returned

Comment: @gusto2 This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand why I get the "code" instead of "id_token". Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the "implicit" grant type, which gives you directly the token.